# Use sed to replace text containing quotes and single quotes

Tags: linux, search, sed, find, xargs

I am trying to search for all files on my server called index.php and then use xargs to run sed to replace some text in those files.

The line I want to find is:

```
echo '<form method="get" class="search_form" action="'.$siteUrl.'">';
```

And after the replacement, it should look like this:

```
echo '<form method="get" class="search_form" action="/">';
```

Therefore, I really only need to change `'.$siteUrl.'` to a single `/`

However, when I try to run this command from an SSH prompt (which I think is right):

```
find . -name "index.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/\'\.\$siteUrl\.\'/"/"/g'
```

it just drops me to a prompt of > and does not go any further...

I have also tried using the same sed command on a single file, which does the same.  Can someone point me out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are replacing text with `/` which is also used as the substitution delimiter. Escape it like this: `\/`
- No need to put double quotes around the replacement since they are already present in the html string.
- Use double quotes around the entire sed expression, to avoid conflict with `'`
- `-print` is the default action for `find` and can be skipped.

Try this:

```
find . -name "index.php" | xargs sed -i "s/'\.\$siteUrl\.'/\//g"
```

Or use a different delimiter for sed, like `:` and remove the escape before `/`:

```
find . -name "index.php" | xargs sed -i "s:'\.\$siteUrl\.':/:g"
```

Oh, and always a good idea to save a backup of edited files (`-i.bak`):

```
find . -name "index.php" | xargs sed -i.bak "s:'\.\$siteUrl\.':/:g"
```

Comment: Thanks - the 2nd one worked a treat!  Happy New Year :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional backup option too.. :)